# Gson library is not working reliably as intended for parsing large JSON file

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to parse a really huge JSON file (file size can get to several GBs), so I cannot just load the entire JSON String into the memory and parse it into an object, I have to somehow read the JSON String line by line and parse it.  I am currently using `JsonReader` from `Gson` library, which was working great, but recently I discovered that it occasionally throws an error saying `Unterminated string at line 1 column xxxxxxxxx path $.fieldname[random index].fieldname[random index].fieldname`, but when I parsed it using a different library like `Jackson`, the parsing went flawlessly (this file is not that huge, only 50 MB so I can just load it into the memory and parse it into an object), so is this a BUG in `Gson`?  And if it is, is there any other JAVA library I can use to do the same thing?  I will be appreciated for any answer!

PS: I am using `gson-2.8.2`

EDIT: I have tested the same file again using `Gson`, the same error occurred but at the different line and different position, so is it confirmed this is BUG in `Gson`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the parsing with `Jackson` library as well and still got the same type of error, however, throughout many tests, it turns out `Gson` and `Jackson` libraries can have a problem (not always) handling JSON file that is NOT pretty printed (meaning that the JSON does not have proper indentation), because all the JSON files I tested are putting the entire JSON string on a single line (technically still a legit JSON), after I formatted it to have indentations, the parsing went through successfully (both `Gson` and `Jackson`), hope this can help anyone who encountered the same issue as I did

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you should check the GitHub issues for `Gson`: https://github.com/google/gson/issues
Apart from that, a minimum example to reproduce that would be good; you could even generate such a file to make the example self-contained ;-)

Btw, please change the heading as you apparently know how to do that. It just does not work reliably with Gson...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I would certainly rename the title

Comment: for providing an example, that could be difficult because of the files that caused the problem is generated from the company I am working with, so this can be confidential

Comment: I thought so, that's why I suggested trying to generate a huge JSON file that can then be used to reproduce the issue with a minimum code example. That way you'd have a good chance that it gets fixed.

Comment: I actually found the issue, see my answer below